# php scripts dont work when called from php tags in html

Tags: server, php, nginx, php-fpm

I have an `nginx` server, with `php5-fpm`, on Ubuntu 15.10.
Files that end in `.php` load properly. HTML files load properly.
But when I put `<?PHP ?>` tags in an html file, the PHP scripts do not load properly. I can see no errors in the nginx, or php5-fpm error logs that shed any light on the issue. View source, in the browser, lists the link to the script, rather than running the script as I would expect.

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
#cat default
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /home/user/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

   # server_name server_domain_name_or_IP;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        autoindex on;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /home/user/public_html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The `php5-fpm` error log is useless:

```
$ sudo cat php5-fpm.log 
[27-Dec-2015 07:55:13] NOTICE: error log file re-opened
```

the nginx error log is equaly unhelpful:

```
$ sudo cat nginx/error.log 
2015/12/29 01:30:20 [notice] 13111#0: signal process started
```

(this was after I reloaded nginx)

Looking at the `nginx` access log, it appears the PHP scripts inside html just never get processed. Unless called directly as in the last entry:

```
var/log$ sudo cat nginx/access.log 
...
192.168.1.10 - - [29/Dec/2015:01:35:32 -0500] "GET /Hnav/www/scripts HTTP/1.1" 301 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
192.168.1.10 - - [29/Dec/2015:01:35:32 -0500] "GET /Hnav/www/scripts/ HTTP/1.1" 200 312 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
192.168.1.10 - - [29/Dec/2015:01:35:34 -0500] "GET /Hnav/www/scripts/sidebar.php HTTP/1.1" 200 614 "http://192.168.1.10/Hnav/www/scripts/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
```

I've been putting up with it for a while, but I've had enough. I really want the `<?PHP ?>` tags in html files to work, and I'm completely stuck. I can provide more detail of necessary, but I am not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the file `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

and add `.html` at the end of the following line:

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .html
```

Comment: I want to note that it now works, `location ~ \.php$|\.html {` and ill test it a bit later with out.  @Nikolay Nikolov and @Tung Tran, Thank you both!

Comment: Did my or Nikolay's answer solve your problem?

Comment: I think it was yours, but I did make his change as well. I made his first, and got access denied.  When I implemented your solution, it worked. I have not removed the location change to nginx yet. But I will test that soon.

Comment: OK, got it. IMHO, it was mine actually. ;-)

Comment: Actually I was added .html in my security.limits_extensions i php-fpm conf and when I remove .html I got access denied too. But without location settings I got blank page , so @TungTran your answer is 50/50 correct :) My is also 50/50 correct and both are 100% correct =) So can you please vote my asnwer up. I'll will vote up Tung's answer too.

Comment: @NikolayNikolov Have you tried to remove `|\.html` on the `location` line though?

Comment: Yes, when I remove it , my test.html shows blank page

Comment: Strange. From my experience, I just needed to append `security.limit_extensions` with `.html` without adding `.html` to `location`.

Answer (score 2):

Open your nginx conf and in section location add : `|\.html` so your location should looks like:

`location ~ \.php$|\.html {`

Just tested and works fine. Adding .html in security.limits_extensions not works for me.

Comment: hmm, im getting access denied.  when i do that.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions provided here will cause all html files to be interpreted with the `php-fpm` process. Unless all your html files include php, this is not very efficient.

A better solution would be to modify your site to only require the files containing php to go through the extra overhead, e.g. by naming them with the `.php` extension.